# "Anymore" in "Are you going to use it anymore?"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Let's say I am in a hostel's kitchen. And I need a knife, but there is only one knife and it is taken. The guy has just chopped up his vegetables and now he is just holding it. Is it natural and correct to use it when I want to know if someone is going to continue to use something. For example:

> Excuse me! Are you going to use the knife **anymore**?

Is that something a native English speaker would say?

Comment: I would say "Have you finished with that knife please?"

Comment: Could I also say "are you done with the knife"?

Comment: Please see an answer posted.

Comment: It sounds perfectly fine to me. (USA native)

Comment: Anymore (one word) meaning 'any longer' is acceptable in US English, but likely to be considered an error in English outside the US. 'Anymore' (one word) meaning 'the slightest quantity more' e.g. 'I don't want anymore cake' is always wrong in all versions of English. It is safe, especially in formal writing, to always use 'any more' (two words) for both meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as Weather Vane suggests, it's not idiomatic.

**Anymore** or **any more** suggests at any future point.

What you want to know is whether the user will need the knife again in the immediate future.

So your requests might be better phrased as one of the following:

> Do you still need (to use) the knife?
>   Are you still using the knife?
>   Do you still require the knife?
>   Have you finished/done with the knife?
>   Do you mind if I borrow the knife (for a few moments/minutes)?